# Sorting dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have dropdown list, which I need to sort. I tried but I am doubtful about that.

My code looks like,

```
    public ActionResult GetAgencyState(string statecode)
    {
        _logger.Info("GetAgencyState: " + statecode);
        AuthUserProfile profile = _sessionHelper.Get<AuthUserProfile>(SessionConstant.LightAUP);
        List<Light_AgenciesState> getAgenciesState = _mcpServiceHelper.GetAgenciesState(
            profile.au_key.ToString(), profile.officernode.ToString(), profile.role, statecode);
        Dictionary<string, string> agenciesState = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        agenciesState = getAgenciesState.ToDictionary(x => x.AgencyKey.ToString(), x => x.AgencyName);
        agenciesState = agenciesState.Count() == 0 ? null : agenciesState;
        agenciesState.OrderBy(agenciesState => agenciesState.Value);
        return Json(agenciesState, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I am getting an error in this line:

```
     agenciesState.OrderBy(agenciesState => agenciesState.Value);
```

My JavaScript code which calls this method:

```
var GetAgencyStateUrl = "/Import/GetAgencyState";
 function OwnerStateFunction() {
var selectedVal = $("option:selected", $("#Ownerstate")).attr("Value");
if (selectedVal != "- select -" && selectedVal != "") {
    $.get(GetAgencyStateUrl, { 'statecode': selectedVal }, function (data) {
  $('#AgentPhone').val("");
        $.map(data, function (value, key) {
            var opt = "<option value=\"" + key + "\">" + value + "</option>";
            $("#OwnerAgency").append(opt);
        });
    }
```

How can I achieve the sorting?

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: I assume you mean `agenciesState = agenciesState.OrderBy(..)`? but if this is for a populating a dropdown, why are you returning a dictionary?

Comment: Do you mean the value is the options display text and the key is the options value? And in the preceding line you can potentially set `agenciesState` to null - how do you thing you can call `OrderBy()` on `null` - it would just throw an exception.

Comment: It does not sort in the controller code! And show the ajax call

Comment: You should not be returning a dictionary - just use `var agenciesState = getAgenciesState.Select(a => new { value = a.AgencyKey, name = a.AgencyName }); return Json(agenciesState, ...);` and in the ajax call - `$.each(data, function(index, item) { $("#OwnerAgency").append($('</option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Name));`

Comment: Then consider marking the answer as accepted so this can be closed out

Answer (score 0):

Replace your error line with this one

```
 agenciesState.OrderBy(a => a.Value);
```

Comment: Show me razor code that you have written for dropdown

Comment: Why are you using javascript? `@Html.DropDownList("ddlName",new SelectList(YourList,"DataValue", "DataKey");` syntax is enough for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you not returning a sorted collection. You use of `agenciesState.OrderBy(agenciesState => agenciesState.Value);` is not assigning the sorted collection to a variable. It would need to be

```
var sorted = agenciesState.OrderBy(agenciesState => agenciesState.Value);
return Json(sorted, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

However there are other issues with your code, including the preceding line

```
agenciesState = agenciesState.Count() == 0 ? null : agenciesState;
```

which means that `agenciesState` could be `null` in which case the following line would throw a exception.

In any case, you should not be returning a dictionary. The controller code can be just

```
public ActionResult GetAgencyState(string statecode)
{
    ....
    List<Light_AgenciesState> getAgenciesState = _mcpServiceHelper.GetAgenciesState(....);
    var agenciesState = getAgenciesState.Select(a => new { Value = a.AgencyKey, Name = a.AgencyName });
}
```

and then in the ajax function

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetAgencyState", "Import")'; // dont hardcode!
var ownerAgency = $("#OwnerAgency"); // cache it

$("#Ownerstate").change(function() {
  var statecode = $(this).val();
  if (!statecode) {
    return;
  }
  $.get(url, { statecode: statecode }, function (data) {
    ownerAgency.empty(); // remove existing options
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      ownerAgency.append($('</option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Name));
    });
  });
});
```

and remove the `onchange="OwnerStateFunction()"` from you html markup.